# Postgres database corruption [solved - not corruption after all]

Tags: postgresql

Postgres version 14.8

I'm having a problem where database tables get silently corrupted. Everything appears to be running properly, but the values returned from queries are incorrect. I can fix the problem by creating a new table with the same structure and copying the records from the corrupted table into the new table. This has happened twice (that I know of since it is invisible until somebody notices an inconsistency).

am_check sees nothing wrong.

Both tables that corrupted are static. They serve SELECT queries, but nothing ever gets changed.

Any advice on how to make this stop or even test for the corruption other than constantly running queries where I know what the right answer should be?

Update to answer @AdrainKlaver:

1. OS: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
2. Last OS update was earlier this year.
3. Both tables had a PK index. One table has an additional index, the other does not.
4. In pgAdmin, I generate the CREATE script, change the table name and all associated names, including the indexes, then use INSERT INTO new_table(SELECT * FROM old_table) to copy the records over.

Update to show query displaying issue
Query on corrupted table:

```
SELECT state, weight157 
FROM imp.get_aging_factors(
    '2019', 
    '2022', 
    'datamod_aging_20220525r2_corrupted', 
    NULL::imp.datamod_aging_20220525r2_corrupted
)
WHERE state=0 OR state = 36
```

Result:

```
state::weight157
0::1.276
36::1.000
```

Query on good table:

```
SELECT state, weight157 
FROM imp.get_aging_factors(
    '2019', 
    '2022', 
    'datamod_aging_20220525r2', 
    NULL::imp.datamod_aging_20220525r2
)
WHERE state=0 OR state = 36
```

Result:

```
state::weight157
0::1.008
36::0.988
```

Comment: Sounds like an index/locale issue to me. More information is needed  1) OS and version. 2) Have you upgraded OS recently? 3) Do you have indexes on the table? 4) How are you copying the data? Add answers as update to question.

Comment: Smells like an hardware issue. Create a backup as soon as possible, first using pg_dump and when you turned off the database server, also a file dump. Check your disks or move to different hardware immediately

Comment: @FrankHeikens: It's an Azure server. I'll ping my IT folks.

Comment: 1) I would try a `REINDEX <table_name>` on the 'corrupted' table first to see if that helps. 2) If that does not work  in `psql` do `CREATE TABLE table_name_new AS SELECT * FROM table_name` 3) Define *... values returned from queries are incorrect*

Comment: @AdrianKlaver: Fixing it is trivial, atm. Knowing it needs to be fixed is not.
By incorrect values, I mean that the sum of a particular field should be 6.3 million and the query returns 8.7 million. When I fix the table, I start getting 6.3 million again. For this particular round anyway. The first table that corrupted thought that no records matched the criteria.

Comment: The description of incorrect values is oversimplified, btw. There are joins and multiplications and function calls and suchlike before the value is summed, but the end result is that it was wrong until I rebuilt the table and then it was right,

Comment: What is the script that is removing the tables doing exactly?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver: Added to question. FWIW, the tables that are corrupting are in the same database, but a different schema.

Comment: Hmm, I don't see anything that stands out in the function. Are the tables dropped used in the query before they are dropped? Is there a view involved? Is there an open transaction? While hardware issues may be in play my suspicion is that this is caused by something else.

Comment: The tables dropped are not used by the query that used the corrupted table. There is not a view involved. There is not an open transaction. I also don't feel like it's hardware, although there may be system functionality in the mix. For example, what happens if Azure's automated backup decides to try to back up an index file while Postgres is doing an autovacuum or something along those lines.

Comment: Sorry, this cannot be answered without more information. Is it the table or the index that is corrupted? If it is index corruption, are you sure that `SELECT bt_index_parent_check('indexname', TRUE, TRUE);` returns no error? If it keeps recurring: is replication involved?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: Replication is not involved. None of the am_check functions return errors.

Comment: Then there is no index corruption. And the table cannot be corrupted, otherwise you wouldn't be able to copy the table to fix the problem. You need to show some SQL statements you are running, their actual result and why you think the result is wrong.

Comment: I agree that this is very weird, which is why I'm seeking help. The query process involves multiple steps and has proprietary elements. There is no simple query I can post. I think it's wrong because on Friday I got an answer. On Monday, the same process returned a different answer. I rebuilt the table and the same process started returning the answer I got on Friday, which is the answer I've been getting for months. I have evidence that the exact same set of queries was run.

Comment: OMG, I see it. The function generates the query by querying information_schema for the columns. For some reason,  that query (which does not have an ORDER BY) has suddenly started returning the columns in a different order than they appear in the table structure, which is putting everything into the wrong fields when the function returns as the table structure. Adding a sort by ordinal position.

Comment: Many thanks to everyone who looked at this. Your questions and comments were very helpful in narrowing down the possibilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function being called generates a query by querying information_schema.columns to get the table columns. Without an ORDER BY on ordinal_position, the information_schema.columns could return the columns in a different order than they appear in the table structure, thereby causing values to appear in the wrong columns in the returned records. Solution is to add ORDER BY ordinal_position to the information_schema.columns query.